# I can't get ERC20 token sweep from a contract to work

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, erc-20

I wrote this contract below that would create a factory contract which generates user deposit addresses. the user addresses would forward any deposit to the authorized caller on the factory contract, I have also created a function that would sweep ERC20 tokens from the user's deposit wallets.

my issue is that the sweeping function seems to fail each time and I have no idea why!

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21;

//The Factory Contract
contract Factory {

    //Contract Owner
    address public owner;
    //The authorized caller to the Users accounts
    address public authorizedCaller;
    //The suggested Owner Candidate 
    address private ownerCandidate;
    //The suggested authorized Caller Candidate 
    address private authorizedCallerCandidate;
    // contains user wallets
    mapping (address => bool) public UserWallets;
    /*
        the owner Candidate hash of the random 
        generated 256 bit key using keccak256 (web3.sha3)
    */
    bytes32 private ownerCandidateKeyHash;
    /*
        the authorized Caller Candidat hash of the random 
        generated 256 bit key using keccak256 (web3.sha3)
    */
    bytes32 private authorizedCallerCandidateKeyHash;

    // a deposit event to a user contract address
    event Transaction(address from, address to, uint256 value);
    // event about an accepted new owner
    event NewOwner(address owner);
    // event about a new accepted authorized caller
    event NewAuthorizedCaller(address authorizedCaller);
    //event about a new generated user address
    event NewUserWallet(address newWallet);

    function Factory() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        authorizedCaller = msg.sender;
    }

    // the only owner modifier
    modifier onlyOwner {
        assert(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    // the only authorized called modifier
    modifier onlyAuthorizedCaller {
        assert(msg.sender == authorizedCaller);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyUserWallets {
        assert(UserWallets[msg.sender] == true);
        _;
    }

    // the only owner candidtate modifier 
    modifier onlyOwnerCandidate(bytes32 key) {
        assert(msg.sender == ownerCandidate);
        assert(keccak256(key) == ownerCandidateKeyHash);
        _;
    }

    // the only authorized caller  candidtate modifier 
    modifier onlyAuthorizedCallerCandidate(bytes32 key) {
        assert(msg.sender == authorizedCallerCandidate);
        assert(keccak256(key) == authorizedCallerCandidateKeyHash);
        _;
    }

    /* 
        transfer ownership function, create a transfer proposal that needs 
        to be accepted by the new owner candidtate:
        candidate address is needed
        keyHash: generate a 256 bit key and hash it using keccak256 (web3.sha3)
        share the key with the candidate through a secure communication channel

    */

    function transferOwnership(address candidate, bytes32 keyHash) public onlyOwner {
        ownerCandidate = candidate;
        ownerCandidateKeyHash = keyHash;
    }
    /*
        the candidate needs to have the key that generates the correct hash
        to be able to accept ownership of the contract, the key should be 
        communicated through secure channels
    */
    function acceptOwnership(bytes32 key) external onlyOwnerCandidate(key) {
        owner = ownerCandidate;
        emit NewOwner(ownerCandidate);
    }

    /* 
        change the Authorized caller function, create a transfer proposal that needs 
        to be accepted by the new Authorized caller candidtate:
        candidate address is needed
        keyHash: generate a 256 bit key and hash it using keccak256 (web3.sha3)
        share the key with the candidate through a secure communication channel

    */

    function changeAuthorizedCaller(address candidate, bytes32 keyHash) public onlyOwner {
        authorizedCallerCandidate = candidate;
        authorizedCallerCandidateKeyHash = keyHash;

    }

    /*
        the candidate needs to have the key that generates the correct hash
        to be able to accept ownership of the contract, the key should be 
        communicated through secure channels
    */

    function acceptAuthorization(bytes32 key) external onlyAuthorizedCallerCandidate(key) {
        authorizedCaller = authorizedCallerCandidate;
        emit NewAuthorizedCaller(authorizedCallerCandidate);
    }


    // this function generates users wallets
    function CreateNewUserWallet() public onlyAuthorizedCaller returns (address newWallet) {
        newWallet = new UserWallet(address(this));
        UserWallets[newWallet] = true;
        emit NewUserWallet(newWallet);
    }

    // in case we need to make some calls using this contract
    function execute(address to, uint256 value, bytes data) public onlyAuthorizedCaller {
        require(to.call.value(value)(data));
    }

    // the function logs value transactions to a user wallet
    function LogTransaction(address from, address to, uint256 value) external onlyUserWallets {
        emit Transaction(from, to, value);
    }
}

// User wallet 
contract UserWallet {
    Factory FactoryContract;
    /* 
       a Modifier to make sure that ony the Authorized caller 
       can call some functions  
    */

    function UserWallet(address _FactoryContract) public {
        FactoryContract = Factory(_FactoryContract);
    }

    modifier onlyAuthorizedCaller {
        assert(msg.sender == FactoryContract.authorizedCaller());
        _;
    }
    /* 
       Allow payments and sweep them automatically to the Authorized caller's address
    */
    function() public payable {
        if (msg.value > 0) {
            FactoryContract.authorizedCaller().transfer(msg.value); 
            FactoryContract.LogTransaction(msg.sender, this, msg.value);
        }
    }
    /*  
        Sweep ERC20 tokens sent to this wallet by simple providing  
        the token Contract Address (ERC20 contract address)
    */
    function SweepTokens(address tokenContractAddress) public onlyAuthorizedCaller {
        ERC20Interface Token = ERC20Interface(tokenContractAddress);
        address Wallet = address(this);
        address AuthorizedCaller = FactoryContract.authorizedCaller();
        uint256 TokenBalance = Token.balanceOf(Wallet);
        if (TokenBalance > 0) {
            require(Token.transfer(AuthorizedCaller, TokenBalance));
        }

    }
    /*  
        execute function allow us to still execute any call on 
        this contract making it almost like a normal account address
    */
    function execute(address to, uint256 value, bytes data) public onlyAuthorizedCaller {
        require(to.call.value(value)(data));
    }
}

// ERC20 Interface
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}
```

[Factory example on ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x208e6dac83586e93a87084eb158c189eb174d82d1be133498809b920c408442e)

[User wallet example on Ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xaf06e8219a6432b9e903c54fd391e3fe296da814)

[Failing sweep transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xde501ece179157655e9b644e2a01ed2019f10fdf5b2b9dff22a737c7b5f6e813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what is the issue, the ERC20 token I was testing with has only doesn't seem to allow sweeping the exact balance, if I subtract a decimal point value the transfer would work just fine.

```
uint256 TokenBalance = Token.balanceOf(Wallet) - 1;
```